# Does using Zend Server provide any specific performance enhancements to my PHP code?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

If I install Zend Server, are there any performance improvements to my PHP code, versus say, just using a normal LAMP stack?

If I use ZS + Zend Framework, are there any performance enhancements? I'm trying to figure out Zend Server's reason for existence. So far I don't really see any differences.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Comment: To add to this, I feel like if I wrote a very simple DB access class, that my code would instantly be more efficient and lightweight than running any other Frameworks...

Comment: Nginx or HipHop are going to be faster than Apache. Using an opcode cache like APC is going to make your PHP execute faster. Zend server includes it's own opcode cache, but I'm not sure if it can beat HipHop or Nginx when they are optimized.

Comment: Interesting....so Ngnix / HipHop would pre-compile the PHP, etc...? I'm not familiar with these, so I'll need to do some reading.

Comment: HipHop pre-compiles your code to C/C++. Nginx is just a fast server (perhaps the fastest). If you use Nginx you will need to run PHP as a FastCGI process and you can install APC. If you use HipHop you don't need to do anything (but perhaps change your code to work with it). There are a lot of bad tutorials on the web that claim you still need to run Apache behind Nginx - that's not true. Apache has no use unless you run a shared host and need to isolate users.

Comment: Very cool...thanks for the responses. I'm reading through this stuff and it looks awesome. I'm going to get my IT all over this.

Comment: Do you mean Zend Server or Zend Server CE?

Answer (score 3):

There will be performance enhancements with the inclusion of Optimizer+.  But the reasons for Zend Server are much more than performance.

- Production-based problem resolution with Event Monitoring and Code Tracing.
- Built-in asynchronous program execution with Job Queuing.
- Integrated full page caching.
- Application deployment.
- Cluster-wide event monitoring and aggregation
- Cluster-wide deployment

Those are some of the features that you get out of the box with Zend Server

Comment: This answer only applies to Zend Server but not to Zend Server Community Edition (CE). Just in case, because I'm not sure what the OP meant.

Comment: ^ this.  Currently to get all of those features, the annual license is about ~$2500.  We are a startup where every penny counts, so we're looking to move away from zend server and find a way to implement all of the above features on our own.